# ¿En que estoy fallando?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.1

estoy leyéndome un libro llamado Java y C++ este trae algunos ejercicios y al final se encuentran las soluciones.  Este es el código realizado por el autor pero a mi no me funciona tengo problemas con los saltos de línea .
Esta es la imagen que se debe imprimir por pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
               if(i==0 || i==3){
                   System.out.print("*");
               }else{
                   if(j==0 || j==9){

                       System.out.print("|");
                   }else{

                       System.out.print(" ");
                   }
               }

           }
       }
```

// 
El código da como resultado esto **********| || |**********

Comment: ¿Qué error obtienes al ejecutar este código?

Comment: **********|        ||        |********** Amigo me sale esto , no es un error pero no es el resultado buscado.

Comment: Esto que comentas que es lo que al momento obtienes agregalo a tu pregunta, así los demás sabrán lo que debería salir y lo que obtienes al momento

Comment: Listo ya lo añadí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te agrego el código con las correciones enumeradas como comentarios:

```
    // 1. ciclo for de 0 a 3
     for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
               // 2. primera linea i == 0, última línea i ==2
               if(i==0 || i==2){

                   System.out.print("*");
                   // 3. si es la ultima repetición imprimir salto de linea
                   if(j == 9)
                     System.out.println();

               }else{
                   if(j==0 || j==9){

                       System.out.print("|");

                       // 4. si es la ultima repetición imprimir salto de linea
                       if(j == 9)
                        System.out.println();

                   }else{
                       System.out.print(" ");
                   }
               }

           }
       }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo excelente respuesta.